# Can default visibility in Java Class have a protected member?

Tags: java, default, semantics, protected

In Java, from my point of view,  it does Not make sense for a default-visible class to have a `protected` member.  From my point to view, it does not make sense because
default visibility in Java = package-level
protected visibility in Java = package-level + subclass( regardless of package)

```
class TestClass{

 protected int addIntegers(int a, int b){

       return (a+b);
 } // end of protected addIntegers(int a, int b){

}
```

Am I correct to say that the above code is Nonsense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could very well have a public class Foo in the same package, extending your Base class, and another class Bar in another package, extending Foo and overriding the protected method.

```
package a;

class Base {
    protected void bang() {
    }
}

package a;

public class Foo extends Base {
}

package b;

public class Bar extends Foo {
    @Override
    protected void bang() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Good Catch!!! so that is a way of seeing a protected method belonging to a default visible class in a class Outside the package associated with the default visible class. Good Catch!!!!